# Reading and checking a file's content in C

Tags: c, file

So I am writing a program in C that takes in a few command-line arguments and also reads a file and prints it to standard out. This is my code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
char* file_path;
float a;
float b;
char filedata[200];
if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Error: 4 arguments are required.\n");
    return -1;
}
file_path = argv[1];
a = atof(argv[2]);
b = atof(argv[3]);
if( a == 0.0 ) {
printf("Error: bad float arg\n");
return -1;
}
if( b == 0.0 ) {
printf("Error: bad float arg\n");
return -1;
}
FILE* fp = fopen( file_path, "r");
if( fp == NULL ){
    printf( "Error: bad file; %s\n", file_path);
    return -1;
}
while( fgets( filedata, 200, fp ) ){

 printf("%s", filedata);        
}
    fclose(fp);
}
```

At the very bottom I have began to read a file. What I am trying to do is find files that contain the characters "#A#" and "#B#" and then print an error message when files containing these characters are not present.

Unfortunately, a simple if statement will not work in this scenario as I am not checking for equality but rather whether or not something is present.

If anybody could tell me about any C functions that are able to read and check the contents of a file, along with a few more specifics, then I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What does not work?

Comment: My code as of now works fine. I just want to add additional code that will help me check a file's content and then print an error message when certain characters are not present. But I'm not sure how to do this. This is why I asked this question.

Comment: BTW: you should put an effort indenting your code consistently.

Comment: Use [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read lines of files and `strstr` to check `#A#` and `#B#`

Comment: Maybe you want to learn about [`strstr()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.7)

Comment: @sameerkn -- `getline()` is POSIX, but not Standard C. What is wrong with `fgets()`?

Comment: @DavidBowling : Size of line cannot be predicted and it would be easy for OP, if complete line is available for search.

Comment: There is no evidence in the code of you looking for `#A#` or `#B#`, so it isn't clear where you're having problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking each line (into 'filedata') simply use the **strstr** function to check if it contains that substring "#A#" etc.

if **strstr** finds the substring it will return a pointer to it, otherwise it will return a NULL pointer.

So you should write something like this:

```
if ( strstr(filedata, "#A#") == NULL )
    printf("Error\n");
```

but since you are looking at the entire file for this substring, you need to check all the lines before you conclude that there is an error.